# Connect to XAMPP webapp over LAN with iPodTouch

Tags: wordpress, xampp, ipod-touch, lan, resolve

XAMPP 1.7.4 is hosted on a Win7 Pro system

A webapp located `C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\` is a single index.html file.

I can connect to the site locally like this `http://localhost/webapp/`

An iPodTouch is able to connect to the host over LAN entering the following in the safari browser:

`http://192.168.0.11/`

which resolves to

`http://192.168.0.11/xampp/`

and loads the xampp landing page.

But if I attempt to contact a webapp like this:

`http://192.168.0.11/webapp/`

the address resolves to `http://localhost/webapp/` and the browser cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server.

`http://192.168.0.11:80/webapp/` also produces the above result. I don't think entering the port is necessary anyway since I can reach the xampp landing page in the first example.

All of the above were performed with the following in place:

httpd.conf includes:

```
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

httpd-xampp.conf includes:

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

.htaccess for the webapp includes:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

Presumably there is issue with the resolution of the webapp address getting thrown in to a loop on account of localhost.

How can I force `http://192.168.0.11/webapp/` to load accross the lan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short story is I only need to modify xampp's default installation here:

httpd-xampp.conf

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

to allow the access from any IP

and to modify wp-admin > settings > general

WordPress Address (URL) 192.168.01.11/webapp/
Site Address (URL) 192.168.01.11/webapp/

and finally

**clear the browser cache  !**

I had spent hours making modifications without being able to see the changes because of the browser's cache.

no modification required to httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf, .htaccess or any hosts file